# How to prevent duplicate value to enter in php session array?

Tags: php, session

I am working on shopping cart system so basically, storing data in session when user clicks "add to cart" button.

So I want to prevent user from entering duplicate data.

Tell me how to do this. 
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? show your code. you can edit your question by clicking "edit"

Comment: What exactly are you storing in the session array?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a variable called `foo` in your session, and you want to check if it is already set. Then you can do something like this:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["foo"])) {
    //foo is already set. Handle that in some way.
    echo "Foo is already set!";
}
else
{
    //fo is not set, so lets set it.
    $_SESSION["foo"] = "bar";
}
```

This code will set `foo` to `bar` unless the session variable was already set before. Not sure if this is what you want to do?